# Can I cast a spell and attack in the same turn?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, combat, actions, attack

Specifically I am asking as a level 1 Half-elf Bard. As far as I know he doesn't have any dual wielding capabilities yet, or anything that states he has a bonus action to attack.

So I'm wondering if I can either cast my spells as bonus actions and use my action to attack, or if I can cast the same spell as an action and use my bonus action to attack?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

### 1. Spell as bonus action, *Attack* as action

You *could* do this. Certain (very few!) spells have a casting time of "1 bonus action." As long as you meet all of the other requirements for casting such a spell, there's no reason you can't *Attack* as your action and cast your spell as a bonus action. (And those can happen in either order, too.)

Unfortunately, only one spell that's accessible to a level 1 Bard has that casting time: *Healing Word*.  I imagine you're looking for more spell+sword action than just that....

### 2. Spell as action, *Attack* as bonus action

First off, *everyone can dual-wield*. It's really badly laid out in the PHB, but  on p.195 you'll see the *Two-Weapon Fighting* section--this applies to *all* characters. (It's easy not to catch this, as by this point in the PHB you've passed the Fighter's two-weapon *style* (p.72) and the dual wielder *feat* (p.165). Like I said, the organization's just horrible sometimes.)

Unfortunately, dual-wielding won't help you here: to attack as a bonus action with your second weapon you must have taken the *Attack* action earlier in your turn.

### 3. But I really want to cast a(ny) spell *and* swing a sword!

You are not alone. Since the delineation of the Magic-User and Fighter classes in original D&D players have always wanted to do this, and designers have always made it really hard. In 5e it's largely the action-economy that makes it hard.

How hard is it? Let's take a look at some of the ways to be a spell-sword:

- Your simplest option is already in your class: **choose College of Valor, wait until 14th level.** That gets you the *Battle Magic* class feature: "when you use your action to cast a Bard spell, you can make one weapon attack as a bonus action."

If that's too slow for you, here are some other options:

- Take two levels of Fighter, any archetype, gaining the *Action Surge* class feature. This'll get you one extra action on your turn: you can cast a spell as one (standard) action and Attack as one (standard) action. But you can only do this once per rest.
- Or take three levels of Sorcerer for Metamagic (Quickened Spell). With your sorcery points you can convert the casting time of a spell from 1 action to 1 bonus action. But you've only got three points, and need to keep taking Sorcerer levels if you want to accrue more points.
- Next up is to take three levels of Cleric, gaining access to the spell *Spiritual Weapon.* Cast that and, for one minute, you've got the ability to move the weapon up to 20' and execute its attack, *all as a bonus action*. This leaves your standard action with which to cast a(nother) spell. Perhaps not quite the "sword-and-spell" style you're going for, but at least it's "spell-*cum*-sword-and-spell". (You could also wait until Bard 10 and take *Spiritual Weapon* as your Magical Secret, as @Escroteitor points out, to the same effect.)
- What you're imagining sounds like what you get if you take seven levels of Fighter (Eldritch Knight archetype) to gain the *War Magic* class feature: "when you use your action to cast a *cantrip*, you can make one weapon attack as a bonus action." (PHB p.75, emphasis mine) With this option you can spam away your damage-cantrips, swing for the fences with your sword, singing away merrily the whole time, and all rather quicker than if you'd waited until Bard 14.

Comment: And never forget the all-important _haste_ spell.